# Weird problem with my mesh collapsing in on itself when posed at certain angles

Tags: mesh, armature, bones, weight-painting, rigify

I'm a bit new when it comes to Blender, so I'm hoping this an easy fix.

I was applying the skin weights to my character, when I noticed this problem where my character's mesh will collapse in on itself if they are leaning to their right. [image]If they lean to the left, it jumps back to normal. [image]

I checked to see if any other bones were influencing that specific region, but as far as I can tell, the torso bone is the only bone affecting that part of the mesh. This is the only bone that seems to be having the issue. 
I used the Rigify plugin to make the rig.